# V4L2 / Beaglebone Black / Radiumboard HD Camera / Controls

Tags: beagleboneblack, v4l2

I am trying to take snapshots with a Beaglebone Black paired with a RadiumBoards HD Camera Cape. I've noticed that using the built-in application (like cheese) will auto-adjust exposure. However, if I write custom C/C++ code on top of the v4l2 libraries to take a snapshot, the exposure is off (too bright or too dark, rarely correct). I would like to be able to either manually adjust exposure or allow the camera to auto-adjust. How can I do this in C/C++ source code?

Resources online indicate that I can change exposure settings through v4l2-ctl. This doesn't work for me. When I issue v4l2-ctl -l to list available controls, I get none.

The driver is reported as cssp_camera version 3.8.13.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if this is the issue, but you may try to specify the device that you want to control. 
Assuming that is /dev/video0, you may do that by:

```
$ v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -l
```

I am also assuming that you have granted permissions to the device.
Hope that I have helped.

Cheers